# List all pages / addresses for a site url in R

Tags: r, curl, rcurl

I want all the available addresses/web pages of a url. For example starting with these:

```
url <- "http://www.rstudio.com/"
url <- "http://www.rstudio.com/resources/"
```

how do I get a list of all the downstream bits i.e.

list of `http://www.rstudio.com/*` or `http://www.rstudio.com/resources/*`.

I have tried (with `library(RCurl)`):

`getURL(url, ftp.use.epsv = FALSE, ftplistonly = TRUE, crlf = TRUE)`

which works for an ftp site but not for http. please help.